# Is it possible to classify Liquibase changesets

Tags: liquibase

I would like to classify Liquibase changesets like

- "must run" (e.g. add column)
- "can run" (e.g. change column size)

Is there a way to do something like that?

The reason to do this is that the execution of changesets should not stop if a changeset from class "can run" runs in a ValidationFailedException or something similar.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can mark your changesets with an attribute

> failOnError

Example:

```
<changeSet id="changeset1" failOnError="true">
   <!-- do important stuff here -->
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="changeset2" failOnError="false">
   <!-- do not so important stuff here -->
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Tried to use 'failOnError' but this does not work as there is an invalidMD5Sum entry in ValidatingVisitor so check of validationPassed will fail and no additional ChangeSet will be executed. Any other idea?

Why is 'failOnError' ignored for checksum check?

Comment: Perhaps this documentation gives you some helpful information http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html

Comment: Unfortunately not. If I set failOnError="false" the migration will fail (and stop additional changeset excecution) in case of a ValidationFailedException. So for me this sounds like a bug! Or the wording 'error' in failOnError should be defined. May be a ValidationFailedException is an bigger issue than defined by failOnError?!